# Joining shafts to resist twisting force

Tags: metal

I need to join two round metal shafts in such a way as to effectively transfer torque between them. I'm not able to add very much external linkage, just a coupling cuff around the joint to force them to stay aligned.

So I need to be able to cut a "key" and "lock" into the 2 ends so that the torque will be transferred from one to the other without trying to twist the joint apart.

Is there a standard way of doing this? I have fairly minimal metal working hand tools so simplicity of the joint is more important than effectiveness.

My current thinking is to use a "halving joint" like this:

[image: Halving Joint]

A "mortise-and-tenon" will be more effective but I think will be far too difficult to prepare:
[image]
Is there a method that can be easily cut and also provide a strong interface?

Comment: Do you folks think this should be migrated to Eng.SE?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I agree this sits somewhere between this site and Eng.SE - I am a member there too - but my lack of skills and tools would probably make them ignore the question I think.

Answer (score 3):

You are making this much more complicated than it needs to be. A coupler with two or four set screws is all that is needed.

[image]

If the thickness of the coupler is too much then use a thinner tubing and just drill two holes all the way through the tubing and the ends of the two shafts. Then insert a small diameter pin through the holes. The pin can be held in place by using a center punch on each end of the pin to expand it slightly so that it rivets itself into the hole in the tubing.

For really light duty work the tubing could even be brass and use a pin that can be simply soldered to the tubing.

All these ideas can be implemented with the most basic tools.

Comment: This was my original intention and, in fact, I already have exactly this sort of coupler with set screws that I'm going to use. It just occurred to me that I can greatly increase the amount of torque the joint will take if I were to make some sort of additional interlocking on the ends of the shafts, thereby allowing the coupler to just resist the tendency to pull apart, rather than convey the torque as well.

Comment: Well a good idea for many use cases, this isn't what I would consider a high torque solution unless the studs were drilled and tapped into the shaft.

Comment: Do the same thing, but put pins all the way through the shafts. Short of the shafts totally self destructing, that would handle any torque.

Comment: @Lefty - I think you should take a look at how many pulleys are attached to motor shafts. Most of them use set screws and are used in torque transfer applications. The next step up is a flat on one side of the shaft against which the set screw engages. The highest torque applications where shafts are larger than say 0.5" in diameter is the use of a key way on both the shaft and inside the hub into which a key is inserted.  http://www.couplinganswers.com/2015/03/why-power-transmission-shafts-have-keys-and-keyways.html

Comment: I like the idea of the keyway, if I can think of an easy way to implement that, it might be my preference. I have an angle grinder that I can use to create a small channel between the two pieces, then I just need something to go into the slot. Maybe some epoxy will do it?

Comment: @Lefty -- make a slot shaped to fit a Woodruff key, those are stock items at industrial-supply places

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I've never heard of a Woodruff Key, but having just Googled it, and seen that it's an arc-shaped piece of metal, it occurred to me that I could just cut a slot using the multi-tool, then use part of a *washer* to fill the slot and act as the key. I think this will  greatly increase the strength of the joint above the coupler/set-screws alone.